# Retrieving an element of each item in an array

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

This is the content of the textfile I am using:

```
[{"name": "Bitcoin", "symbol": "BTC", "rank": 1, "slug": "bitcoin", "tokens": ["Bitcoin", "bitcoin", "BTC"], "id": 1},
 {"name": "Ethereum", "symbol": "ETH", "rank": 2, "slug": "ethereum", "tokens": ["Ethereum", "ethereum", "ETH"], "id": 1027}, ... ]
```

How do I retrieve each "name" element of each coin and save it into a temporary variable?

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a valid [`JSON`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), so just use the built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to parse it, e.g.:

```
import json

with open("path/to/your_file.txt", "r") as f:  # open the file for reading
    data = json.load(f)  # parse it as JSON

# now you can access the data hierarchically, i.e.
print("The first coin is {} and its symbol is {}".format(data[0]["name"], data[0]["symbol"]))
# The first coin is Bitcoin and its symbol is BTC

# or if you want just a list of all names
coin_names = [d["name"] for d in data]  # ['Bitcoin', 'Ethereum', ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable using a 3rd party library, `pandas` accepts a list of dictionaries directly:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import json

mystr = StringIO("""[{"name": "Bitcoin", "symbol": "BTC", "rank": 1, 
"slug": "bitcoin", "tokens": ["Bitcoin", "bitcoin", "BTC"], "id": 1},
 {"name": "Ethereum", "symbol": "ETH", "rank": 2, "slug": "ethereum", 
 "tokens": ["Ethereum", "ethereum", "ETH"], "id": 1027}]""")

# replace mystr with 'file.json'
df = pd.read_json(mystr)

# extract names to list
res = df['name'].tolist()

print(res)

['Bitcoin', 'Ethereum']
```